# Resizing built-in wordpress video not working!

Tags: videos, video-player

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VUq9.jpg

I'm using the wordpress video plugin and it's not resizing the video when I do it inline of the shortcode & when I try doing it from the styles.css. I also tried using the "FitVids" plugin, again no success. help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to place this in your style.css

```
embed, iframe, object, video {
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```